# Detect scroll down inside "body"

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an app inside a Facebook iframe and need to know when the user is scrolling down, inside the body. This code I have right now is only detecting the whole window. But I can't get it to work so it fires inside the body.

Any ideas how I can modify this?

```
//lastAddedLiveFunc();
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
    var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

    if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
     //console.log('scroll bottom');
     lastAddedLiveFunc();
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe you could try with the ID of the container you're trying to detect the scroll in? $("#selector").scroll(function()... maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but then it doesn't fire anything :(

Comment: Kim - I just had the problem of it not working as well. However, it turned out a wrapping div was actually getting the scroll event fired, not the div I would initially suspect.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('scroll', function (e){
    if ($('#selector').has($(e.target)).length){                       
     //do what you want here
    }
});
```

I use this mostly for touch devices, but no harm in trying it out :)